# Django - Add two names - Couldn't print results

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django.

Trying to build an app that adds two names. Pretty Basic.

Built a page that collects the names but not printing the final result.

Here is my code:

**urls.py - inside the app**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home, name='home'),
    path('add',views.addname,name='add')
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request,'input.html')

def addname(request):
    val1 = (request.POST['fname'])
    val2 = (request.POST['lname'])
    res = 'Hi' + val1 +val2

    return render(request, 'resultprint.html',{'resultprint':res})
```

**templates/input.html**

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Hello!</h1>

<form action='addname' method='post'>

    {% csrf_token %}
    Enter 1st name : <input type='text' name='fname'><br>
    Enter 2nd name : <input type='text' name='lname'><br>
    <input type='submit'>

</form>    


{%endblock%}
```

**templates/resultprint.html**

```
{% block content %}

Result: {{resultprint}}

{%endblock%}
```

Below are the screenshots:
[image: screenshot 2]

[image]

Couldn't really find where is the mistake happening.

I added the templates and app in the Settings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the same url in your urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('addname', views.addname, name='addname')
]
```

But you can use directly the name of the url in your html file like that :

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Hello!</h1>

<form action='{% url 'addname' %}' method='post'>

    {% csrf_token %}
    Enter 1st name : <input type='text' name='fname'><br>
    Enter 2nd name : <input type='text' name='lname'><br>
    <input type='submit'>

</form>    


{%endblock%}
```